# Simple Jasper report without a database

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I'm totally new in jasperforge || jasperreports and I wish to generate a simple pdf report using only an ireport empty template and **no database connections**.

I tried to adapt some simple program to just export the PDF without no data and tried the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporterParameter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader;


public class JasperTest {

    public void generateReport() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, JRException {
        System.out.println("Filling report...");
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper_filename, hm);
        JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, pdf_filename);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
        exporter.exportReport();
        System.out.println("Created file: " + pdf_filename);
        System.out.println("Done!");
    }
    String jasper_filename = "/blue_template.jasper";
    String pdf_filename = "/pdf_out.pdf";
    HashMap hm = new HashMap();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, JRException {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        new JasperTest().generateReport();
    }
}
```

,...but it didn't work. I needed to add the following libraries to the project:

- commons-logging
- commons-digester
- commons-collections

When I tried to run the executable I've got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilationFailedException
```

I thought that's not related to .jasper file, that was compiled without errors in ireports, but I don't have any clue of whats happening.

Comment: Did you try to add the groovy library/classes? This is not a runtime error, but an error while loading a class definition which uses a groovy class.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding groovy library. It will fix the problem. http://groovy.codehaus.org/Download

Answer (score 0):

Jasper doesn't depend on groovy unless report language is "groovy". Reports compiled in iReport for some reason have groovy by default. To change it please right click on report root, Properties, set language to Java and recompile.